CORS Error with Supabase auth.signUp in Local Development
I'm doing my first steps with Supabase in Nuxt, and I'm encountering a CORS error when trying to register a user with auth.signUp. Here's the code I'm using:
async function registerUser() {
    const { error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
        email: form.email.value,
        password: form.password1.value,
        options: {
            display_name: form.username.value, // Custom field
        },
    });

    if (error) {
        console.error("Error signing up:", error.message);
    } else {
        console.log("User registered successfully");
    }
}

When I make the request, the browser shows a CORS error. Below is the request header captured in the browser:

Request URL: http://localhost:54323/auth/v1/signup
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional Headers:

apikey
Authorization
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:3000/



Here is my Supabase password configuration:
# in emails.
site_url = "http://localhost:3000/"
additional_redirect_urls = ["http://localhost:3000/"]
jwt_expiry = 3600
enable_refresh_token_rotation = true
refresh_token_reuse_interval = 10
enable_signup = true
enable_anonymous_sign_ins = false
enable_manual_linking = false
minimum_password_length = 6
password_requirements = ""

